# Not a valid month error in oracle

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT c.CYCLE_OID,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN a.NAME = 'Loading' 
    THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' 
END) AS LOAD_COUNT from CYCLE c 
INNER JOIN mssolhist.CYCLEACTIVITYCOMPONENT a on a.OID = c.CYCLE_OID
WHERE c.STARTTIME_UTC >= to_date(to_char(sysdate-10,'dd-MM-yyyy')) AND     c.ENDTIME_UTC <= to_date(to_char(sysdate-5,'dd-MM-yyyy'))
GROUP BY c.CYCLE_OID 

ORA-01843: not a valid month

; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

I am getting a not valid month error in oracle when using this to_date expression. I have no idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there are two ways to avoid the error.

First, you are trying to convert `date` to string, then to `date` again. You don't need to do this. Just use date as it is.

```
WHERE c.STARTTIME_UTC >= sysdate-10 AND c.ENDTIME_UTC <= sysdate-5
```

If you want to truncate time part, then use `trunc` function.

```
WHERE c.STARTTIME_UTC >= trunc(sysdate-10) AND trunc(c.ENDTIME_UTC <= sysdate-5)
```

Or, if there's a special reason to use `to_char`, then you'd better to specify the date format when you try to convert string to `date`.

```
WHERE c.STARTTIME_UTC >= to_date(to_char(sysdate-10,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
  AND c.ENDTIME_UTC <= to_date(to_char(sysdate-5,'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

`to_date` function has optional `fmt` parameter. If you omit `fmt`, default format will be used. default format is determined implicitly by `NLS_TERRITORY` or can be set explicitly by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter.

Comment: My original sql query passes in sql developer but failing in when I try to run it via jenkins.

Comment: Perhaps sql developer and your database server has different value of `nls_date_format`. It seems that the default format worked in your sql client. But dbms has different value of the parameter which cause the problem.

Answer (score 2):

instied of   to_date(to_char(sysdate-10,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')

to_date(to_char(sysdate-10,'dd-mon-yyyy'),'dd-mon-yyyy')

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query and it will work fine.

```
SELECT c.CYCLE_OID,
SUM(CASE 
WHEN a.NAME = 'Loading' 
    THEN '1' 
ELSE '0' 
END) AS LOAD_COUNT from CYCLE c 
INNER JOIN mssolhist.CYCLEACTIVITYCOMPONENT a on a.OID = c.CYCLE_OID
WHERE c.STARTTIME_UTC >= to_date(to_char(sysdate-10,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy') AND     c.ENDTIME_UTC <= to_date(to_char(sysdate-5,'dd-MM-yyyy'),'dd-MM-yyyy')
GROUP BY c.CYCLE_OID
```